# Trim mp4 files without encoding it again

Tags: matlab, video, encoding, ffmpeg, trim

I have a .mp4 video file, I need to trim it, however no matter how I do it, trimmed video is being encoded again which results in noisy video.

What I've tried:

1. Open video with Matlab, read frames and write only the frames that I want to have in trimmed video, I use `'MPEG-4'` option.
2. Trim video using Windows Movie Maker.
3. Trim video using VirtualDub.

In first 2 scenarios original mp4 movie is encoded again after trimming it. I couldn't get mp4 files open in VirtualDub.

So what would be the easiest way to trim a video without re-encdong it?

Comment: @rayryeng could you give more detail?

Comment: Apologies, I made a wrong statement.  It isn't possible to crop without reencoding.  The reason why is because it's mainly due to the way MPEG-4 works.  Motion information is encoded in essentially blobs.  You are tracking how blobs move over space and cropping will modify the way this information is being stored.  You don't have a choice but to reencode.  See this post for more detail: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/crop-video-in-ffmpeg-without-re-encoding

Comment: @rayryeng So if I have an mp4 video and I'd like to crop middle 20 seconds, no matter what I do, I will always lose information when doing so. Is that right?

Comment: I think you mean trim, not crop (which would decrease the the dimension of each frame). Matlab is a terrible tool for this sort of thing.

Comment: That isn't cropping.  That is trimming the video.  In that case yes it's possible without reencoding.  FFMPEG is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @horchler yes, trim!

Comment: @guneykayim see here.  Use FFMPEG or `mencoder`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59383/extract-part-of-a-video-with-a-one-line-command/59388.  Don't use MATLAB at all.  Reading in video, trimming out what you need then writing using MATLAB will ultimately reencode the video.  Use something else.

Comment: @rayryeng can I trim several parts into one file using ffmpeg, or do I need to trim several times and merge them?

Comment: @guneykayim That is certainly possible.  You'd have to extract out multiple videos then merge them all in the end.  Use the `concat` command: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate.  This **only** works if all videos have the same audio and video codecs, which will be the case if you are extract portions of the same video.  As such, make a `bash` script with the desired start and end times for each clip you want to extract, loop it in bash and create individual files, then merge everything with the `concat` command.

Comment: @rayryeng perfect, one last question, can I do it by giving the frame numbers instead of times?

Comment: @guneykayim Doing a quick search in FFMPEG's documentation.... I don't see any such utility. I only see time - http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options. However, if you know the frame rate, you can easily convert between the frame number and time by doing `time = frame_number/FPS` where `FPS` is the frame rate of your video (i.e. 24 Hz). Therefore, if your FPS was 24 Hz for example, at frame 24 you should be at the 1 second mark for video.

Comment: BTW, the `concat` doc page I linked above has a bash script that will concatenate files given an input directory.  First create your series of videos by trimming out the portions you need then use the `concat` option after you're done.  I'd write an answer but I've never used FFMPEG in this regard before so I wouldn't be confident in what I'm writing. Good luck though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the split and re-encode in one command.

Create a text file, `list.txt`,

like this

```
file 'in.mp4'
inpoint 48.101
outpoint 67.459
file 'in.mp4'
inpoint 76.178
outpoint 86.399
file 'in.mp4'
inpoint 112.140
outpoint 125.031
```

then run,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -an -crf 18 out_merged.mp4
```

Comment: I don't want re-encoding?

Comment: The first step in your workflow is already re-encoding i.e. transcoding.

Comment: Then it is not what I want, how do I do it without re-encoding? I don't want to lose information again by encoding an already encoded .mp4 file.

Comment: For accurate cuts, not possible. If you add `-crf 18` or lower, the difference isn't significant

Comment: Could you provide full answer with this `-crf 18` option and tell what that exactly does?

Comment: Basically, CRF maintains constant quality, so that complex video gets more bit budget and simpler less. Like 2-pass encoding but in 1 pass

Comment: What happens if I increase or decrease 18?

Comment: Lower CRF gives better quality but larger size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102374/discussion-between-guneykayim-and-mulvya).

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it with the following commands:

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 48.101  -t 19.358 -i in.mp4 -an out_part1.mp4
ffmpeg.exe -ss 76.178  -t 10.221 -i in.mp4 -an out_part2.mp4
ffmpeg.exe -ss 112.140 -t 12.891 -i in.mp4 -an out_part3.mp4

ffmpeg -i out_part1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intrmdt1.ts
ffmpeg -i out_part2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intrmdt2.ts
ffmpeg -i out_part3.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intrmdt3.ts

ffmpeg -i "concat:intrmdt1.ts|intrmdt2.ts|intrmdt3.ts" -c copy out_merged.mp4
```

And some explanation:

1. Giving `-ss (start time)`  and `-t (duration)` options before `-i (input)` option avoids unnecessary decoding.
2. Not using `-c copy` provides transcoding hence result more precise cut (got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150873/ffmpeg-fails-to-copy-correct-duration/35151335#35151335)).
3. I used `-an` because I didn't need the audio, if you need audio just omit this option.
4. Before concatenating the resulting trimmed videos I needed to transcode them to mpeg transport streams, to achieve lossless concatenation (for more details you can see this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)).

Comment: Point 1 is wrong. Getting rid of `-c copy` causes the transcode, -`ss-` and `-t` before `-i` avoids unnecessary decoding.

Comment: @Mulvya how about now?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Great to know you managed to solve it only from some hints from my comments.