# ffmpeg fails to copy correct duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to trim a video with the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 -ss 76 -t 10 -c copy -an out.mp4
```

which exactly means, copy 10 seconds after 76 seconds, and don't copy audio. However `out.mp4` is 5 seconds length.

This is ffmpeg console output:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 -ss 76 -t 10 -c copy -an out.mp4
ffmpeg version N-78197-g5893e87 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzli
b --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblu
ray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab
le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger
 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena
ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --en
able-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --
enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 16.101 / 55. 16.101
  libavcodec     57. 22.102 / 57. 22.102
  libavformat    57. 23.101 / 57. 23.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 27.100 /  6. 27.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
  Duration: 00:02:28.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2018 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1056 [SAR 1:1 DAR 20:11]
, 1887 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default
)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.23.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1056 [SAR 1:1 DAR 20:11],
q=2-31, 1887 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  143 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1502kB time=00:00:09.96 bitrate=1235.5kbits/s speed= 524x
video:1499kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.194616%
```

When I analyze this console output I see this inconsistency. It says output time is `9.96 seconds`. On the other hand it says `frame is 143`, so from the latter information I can calculate `duration` by `frame/fps` which is `143/23.98=5.96`.

Another strange behaviour with this copy command is when I change the start time to something else output video length is varying between 5-10 seconds depending on the start time.

What might be the problem causing these unexpected behaviours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffmpeg only cuts at keyframes, so with inter-coded streams, you may not get exact duration. You'll have to transcode the video for a precise cut.

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 76 -t 10 -i in.mp4 -an out.mp4
```

(Placing the `-ss` and `-t` before the input will make ffmpeg seek to the position and then decode frames. Placing them afterwards means ffmpeg decodes all frames and then discards till start time is reached)